# How to choose (natural) primary key

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

Suppose there is a table keeping info about Vendors and Customers in one table named Partners (since one partner can be vendor at one point of time and customer at other).
Partners table have usual stuff: company name, short name, address, city, country. Now, for domestic partners there is DomesticVatNumber and for non-domestic there is InternationalVatNumber. Usually, vat number would be perfect candidate for primary key but the problem here is that not all domestic partners have InternationalVatNumber and international ones dont have DomesticVatNumber.

I am trying to see best ways to design this in db. Is surrogate key the only option in this case or should i maybe reconsider having domestic and international partners in same table? Should i maybe split them into 2 tables: DomesticPartners (which always have DomesticVatNumber) and InternationalPartners (which always have InternationalVatNumber) and then put primary key on DomesticVat and InternationalVat columns respectively?

What are pros/cons of each approach?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would never make a primary key out of something assigned by an external party, nor would I use a value that the user would ever see. I would always use a meaningless key (either an identity column or a unique identifier).

Given what you are saying, I wouldn't split them into separate tables since you would then have to either have any table that referenced your partner table in a foreign key would either have to have two nullable columns setup to do this or have one column but no foreign key relationship (shudder...).

The best option is to have one table, have the domestic and international VAT numbers as separate fields in the table but not a primary key. Since they will both be nullable, you would have limited options for a unique constraint on them.

Just my 2 cents

Comment: I guess in that case there could be 2 more tables: InternationalVatNumbers and DomesticVatNumbers with FK to Partners table providing optional values for Partners table and eliminating Nullable columns in it?

Comment: Any reason you don't want nullable columns? It seems like a complicated way to avoid nullable columns. Since these two attributes are truly different attributes (even though they are 'vat numbers') I don't see an issue with them being nullable. If you must do another table, I'd do one table with a 'vat number type' and 'vat number' linked back to the partner rather than 2 tables.

Comment: no specific reason, just thinking out loud on that one. Good point with one table and vat number type!

Comment: actually, now when i think about it, isnt having an option of UNIQUE constraint on vat number field one of very good reasons for having two additional tables in which vat numbers would be NOT NULL?

Answer (score 1):

As your business grows, your systems get more complex, and it makes more sense to have one table. An example can be an ENTITIES table which stores everyone and everything, including vendors and customers. This can include individuals, groups and businesses, clients and staff, etc. Later on you will be glad you did it this way, because it reduces the number of complex joins you are going to have with multiple tables. You can use ENTITY_NO as a surrogate key and ENTITY_TYPE to differentiate entities. VAT number fields can be indexed separately and made nullable.

Comment: i am not sure i understand, why i might want to have for example Partners and Stuff in same table? What would be the benefits?

Comment: From my perspective, it's a philosophical choice. I've worked with systems with common entities and there are some advantages in having common code to manage name and contact information. There's some disadvantages around having a more complex data model and having to have some logic to ensure you are referencing proper entity types.

In the systems I've used, the entity table itself didn't have a field for entity type because an entity could be multiple types (it could be a vendor and a customer). 

Personally, I wouldn't go down this route, the advantages aren't necessarily worth it.

Comment: Philosophical  to a point... it's more about being scalable. When you grow to corporate level, instead of having to give each development team ERD's with your complex table structure, and then watch in horror as their juniors write scary SQL joins - just give them an entity structure and they only have one table to join to. If you don't want the table too wide, you can create for example ENTITY_ADDR to store addresses, and so on, but all your offshore developers will know to find all customer/staff/group information in one easy to find structure.